# Problems installing data.table for R

Tags: r, data.table, bioconductor, install.packages

I'm trying to install data.table library for R, but I can't get it to work.I've tried using both CRAN and Bioconductor but I keep getting an error that the package is not available for R 3.2.2:

```
> biocLite('data.table')
 BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
 Using Bioconductor version 3.1 (BiocInstaller 1.18.4), R version 3.2.2.
Installing package(s) ‘data.table’
Warning: unable to access index for repository  
  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository   
https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘datatable’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2) 
> install.packages("data.table")
Warning: unable to access index for repository     
https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘data.table’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

I really have no clue what to do...very new to R.

Comment: What OS are you on? Have you tried `install.packages("data.table", type="source")`?

Comment: I'm working on a unix server with R installed to my home dir. I tried this and got the same error

Comment: Try another mirror. Or try downloading the `tar.gz` file and installing it from disk using `R CMD INSTALL <pkg>.tar.gz`.

Comment: I've had problems with RStudio's https mirror occasionally, too. Use a different mirror.

Comment: Agree with using a different mirror... you can also try `library(devtools); install_github('Rdatatable/data.table')` for the dev version of `data.table` (1.9.5, you know you want it)

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 there is `1.9.7` in git repo already.

Comment: +1 for @C8H10N4O2's answer. One of the advantages of using github version is that you got the latest features of `data.table`. (From my limited experience with devl-version of `data.table`, it is quite stable.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced a similar issue trying to install data.table using RStudio (V 0.99.903) and R (latest version 3.3.1) on windows 8. I issued the command install.packages('data.table') but it failed. What worked for me was running the install.packages with R directly. It got installed properly.

Comment: I was having a different problem installing this same package but this worked for me. Just installed directly with R and everything went smoothly

Answer (score 2):

When RStudio gives a popup to restart the session before package installation, we need to click "Yes". This refreshes RStudio's memory and at the same time, the dataframes in memory won't be lost. After this step, just use the following commands -

```
install.packages("data.table")

library(data.table)
```

and data.table is installed and loaded

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem.  I realized that I hadn't restarted since re-installinging R.  After restarting, the problem vanished.

Comment: Since this is about a suggestion to try something and see if it works, a more appropriate placement of this would be the comments section :)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the *data.table* folder created in my documents after installation then I went ahead to re-install the package and it worked.