# Issues installing data.table in R 3.6.3 (Oct 2020)

Tags: r, data.table, install.packages

I'm using a Mac with OS Sierra 10.12.5. I'm having trouble with installing the R package "data.table," including if I try to install via install.packages("Hmisc"), or install.packages("data.table"). Both result in:

```
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-data.table/00new/data.table/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘datatable.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/data.table’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/bl/lgd7_j2j087f24tcly84xg580000gn/T/RtmpbM5EaD/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("data.table") :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
```

I then tried installing directly from the .zip at: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table, but got the following "not available for R 3.6.3" message:

```
> install.packages("~/Downloads/data.table-master.zip")
Warning message:
package ‘~/Downloads/data.table-master.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

I tried the approaches in this thread, but none worked :\ : [Problems installing data.table for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721775/problems-installing-data-table-for-r/38762586)

Any advice for what I can try next, or where I can access a version of data.table specifically for R 3.6.3?

Comment: Two thoughts: (1) though I don't have a mac, I've seen several questions resolved by reinstalling or updating `xcode`. (2) You can install binary packages using RStudio's public package manager, see https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/07/01/announcing-public-package-manager/.

Comment: #2 Did the trick! Thanks! For anyone in the future reading this, just open in Rstudio, install.packages("data.table") and it should say there is a binary version available. Then it asks if you want to install from sources, and you should respond "no." This will download the binary package and from there you can just load it with "library(data.table)" just fine. This also worked for my data.table-related problem in library(Hmisc) :D